# Collection of negatively charged aerosols

Tags: electrostatics

Is it possible to charge aerosols suspended in air using an ion generator and collect them approx. meters away by a positive charged electrode?

Comment: Yes, this is done in power-plants to separate dust: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_filter

Comment: Thanks @SebastianRiese in industrial ESPs there is always an active electric field that guides particles to the oppositely charged electrode. I meant more random collection of charged particles as they are entrained by the air currents.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing by "aerosols" you mean the particle phase of an aerosol, then yes it can be done and is common practice in aerosol physics, when aiming for particle size distributions of an aerosol or generating a monodispers/monomobile aerosol (see also electromobility spectrometry (EMS)).

EMS requires the particles of interest to carry electric charges (= to be charged). This is done e.g. by guiding the aerosol through a so called neutralizer (or charger). The neutralizer consists of a radiation source responsible for ionizing the carrier gas' (= aerosol gas phase) molecules. Within the resulting ion-aerosol-mixture, aerosol particles acquire charges upon colliding with ions and interchange charges by colliding with each others. For a sufficient ion concentration - thus a radiation source strong enough - and a sufficient time the aerosol is exposed to the radiation a steady state establishes. It is defined by balanced charge fluxes, that is the fraction of particles carrying $i$ (for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$) elementary charges (or short: $i$-fold charged particles) remains constant (see Wiedensohler approximation (Wiedensohler, 1988)).

However, exposing a charged particle to an electric field influences its trajectory within the stream depending on: the strength of the electric field, the mass of the particle, the amount of elementary charges it carries, etc.
It is possible to calculate the trajectory of the particle when all these parameters are known. The Differential Mobility Analyzer (DMA) - similar to a mass spectrometer - basically operates on the principle of forcing particles of a certain size (or more precise: electrical mobility), which is controlled by an adjustable electric field, into a well defined trajectory. Particles with different electric mobilites (e.g with different masses or differently charged) are not capable of following the set trajectory, since their paths are either more or less influenced by the field.

Although this is a drastically simplified explanation of the processes and instrumentation involved, while there are other things to consider still, the answer to your question is: Yes, it is possible to segregate/collect particles with the measures portrayed previously.